# Hard-coded @RequestMapping URL in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm studying Spring 3 and I'm using it in a simple web-application.

Now I'm implementing a Spring MVC Controller using annotations, and I'm wondering:
Is there any best practice using `@RequestMapping` annotation?

I mean: I've seen that usually the URL mapped in this annotation is hardcoded in the class...
**Is there a way to pass the URL in a 'loosely coupled way' (to obtain a more reusable class)?**

I know that there are some *wild cards* that can be used, but I think that isn't the solution... Am I wrong?

**EDIT:**

I add an example to better explain my doubt.

Suppose I want my controller to be triggered by a request to `/foo/bar/baz/mypage.htm`, in my controller the handler method will be annotated with `@RequestMapping("/foo/bar/baz/mypage")`.

Now I decide to change the URL triggering my controller into `/foo/bar/otherpage.htm`, so i need to edit my class, put `@RequestMapping("/foo/bar/otherpage")` on my handler method, recompile the project and deploy it again.

It seems to me not so practical...

Comment: What does 'dynamic url' mean? Constructed at runtime? In your java code?

Comment: @soulcheck Sorry... 'Dynamic' it's not the right word... What I mean is, passing an URL to the annotation without hardcoding it into the class.
I could say in 'loosely coupled way'.
(I've edited the post)

Comment: @David C.: Why do you want to do this. -- "Is there any best practice..." I asked because Best Practice is always motivated form a reason.

Comment: @Ralph I think it could be useful to have a parametrized URL in the `@RequestMapping` annotation. For example, if I decide to change the 'path' to a page, I need to modify the url in the class, recompile and re-deploy the application. Right?
Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Ask yourself how often you (dynamically) change URL patterns in an existing application and if it's worth the effort to build support for it. In my experience, it's typically only done as part of larger refactorings, in which case your application gets rebuilt/redeployed anyway.

Comment: @David C. I strongly agree with pap. And the worst thing is not to change the url in the controll, thats easy. The more worst thing is to change the url in every JSP or other controller that redirects. -- May you should start thinking of URLs in a RESTfull way, the should be chosen very carefully so that you do not rename them so often.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm worried about an unexisting problem... :)
Thanks to Ralph and pap.

Comment: A little late to the discussion, but I want to chime in here.  I think that there's a huge use case for having a web app respond to URLs dynamically.  For example, let's say you're creating a CMS, and you allow users to enter their own URLs into a field somewhere when creating a new CMS page.  How, then, do you tell Spring MVC to route said URL to a particular controller?  I'm having the same issue right now with an e-commerce app where admins are allowed to enter their own URLs when creating products and categories.  So I think the original question is quite valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently annotated controllers aren't very configurable.

As far as I know, the only possible approach to this problem is to use alternative [`HandlerMapping`s](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html) in order to configure "base URLs" of controllers. For example, as follows:

```
// Note the absense of @Controller to prevent this controller
// from being discovered by DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping
public class FooController {
    @RequestMapping("/list") public String list(...) { ... }
    @ReqeustMapping("/save") public String save(...) { ... }
}
```

.

```
<bean 
    class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerBeanNameHandlerMapping" />

<bean name = "/foo" class = "FooController" />
<bean name = "/bar" class = "FooController" />
```

In this example two instances of `FooController` handle `/foo/list`, `/foo/save`, `/bar/list` and `/bar/save` respectively.

The upcoming Spring 3.1 will have an improved Spring 3.1 architecture ([Spring 3.1 M2: Spring MVC Enhancements](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements-2/)) that seems to be more flexible, though I haven't checked it yet.

Comment: Spring 3.1 M2: Spring  MVC Enhancements  - moved to 
https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/13/spring-3-1-m2-spring-mvc-enhancements

Comment: And this is probably not supported since Spring 3.1

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. If you wanted to change the pages that matched a controller you'd need to change a file somewhere. Would you rather change the file with the related code underneath it, *or* would you rather work with some XML files that specifies the URL and the class, and then you have to worry about the file being in the right place during runtime?

As there should be [almost no code in your controller](http://www.google.ca/search?aq=0&oq=fat+models+skinny&gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=fat+models+skinny+controllers#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=DSR&channel=cs&source=hp&q=%22fat+models%22+%22skinny+controllers%22&pbx=1&oq=%22fat+models%22+%22skinny+controllers%22&aq=f&aqi=g-v3g-j1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=50825l55015l0l55321l4l4l0l0l0l0l213l619l1.2.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=c40befabedf3bbd3&biw=1680&bih=932) anyway, you should think of your controllers as compilable configuration files. Also, if you are using a build system like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/)  and not compiling individual files by hand using Javac then compilation time shouldn't be an issue. If it becomes one, it's probably time to split your project into sub-projects.

I think you should just embrace this and see that it is probably not the issue you think it is. Also, did you know that controllers can match to expressions and not just literal strings? That gives you some flexibility in your naming.

If you really want to, you could just fall back to the [Spring 2.0 style XML configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html), but I don't think anyone would recommend that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not a best practice, but have you tryed with @PathVariable annotations?

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/path/{word}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView myRestMethod(@PathVariable String word) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this don't match my issue... :)