# Set Spring MVC Paths in Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

Can Spring MVC paths be set as Java config, rather than using annotations on the controller?

I want to re-use one controller class under different path mappings, and have each instance wired with different service implementations.

For example, the API will look a bit like this:

```
PUT /mysql/some_key/some_value
GET /mysql/some_key
DELETE /mysql/some_key

PUT /oracle/some_key/some_value
GET /oracle/some_key
DELETE /oracle/some_key
```

So there'd be one instance of the controller wired with a `MySqlCrudService` and one instance of the controller with an `OracleCrudService`.

How would one configure this? The controller could have the methods annotated (eg `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/{key}/{value}")`, but when constructing the controller in Java config I'd need to specify the class-level path mapping.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339112/hard-coded-requestmapping-url-in-spring-mvc-controller

Comment: And this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor